# Oracle APEX - how i can change translate action menu language (interactive grid and report)

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to change the language of default UI elements language  in my APEX application to Arabic  language :

[image]

i change the  button (excepted interactive button) and column header language using XLIFF file , but i can't change action menu language , how i can do that if it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create new "messages":

1. Try to find message id:

   ```
   select * 
     from APEX_APPLICATION_TRANSLATIONS
    where WORKSPACE = 'INTERNAL' 
      and message_text = 'Subscription';
   ```
2. Copy TRANSLATABLE_MESSAGE field value (e.g. APEX.IG.SUBSCRIPTION or APEXIR_SUBSCRIPTION) and remember IS_JS_MESSAGE value
3. Go to Shared Components -> Globalization -> Text Messages -> Create Text message
4. Put id id name field (APEX.IG.SUBSCRIPTION)
5. Select your language
6. Fill "Text"
7. Select the same value as already exists in field IS_JS_MESSAGE

Your application language must me the same with this new message.

Comment: thanks, the main language English,  and i need only translate this menu to Arabic when the user  choose Arabic language .

Comment: It's ok, Application Language changes and messages with Arabic language will be used when possible.

Comment: OK,  i do that but the button (column) in actions menu not changed , 
sorry i am not strong in apex , i want change the (columns) to (الأعمده)  , i changed the actions to  (الإجراءات) by button "ID" but  (columns) not changed. 
thanks for your support.

Comment: I try to change by console using ( $('#ar_actions_menu_0').text('jawad') ) ,  and i tried that by dynamic action but the columns button text still (columns).

Comment: Have you changed message for APEX.IG.COLUMNS or APEXIR_COLUMNS? 

And how user can change the application language? I mean Shared components / Globalization Attributes / Application Language Derived From setting. Also you can check current language in developer toolbar - session.
And is it grid or report?

Comment: i changed  APEXIR_COLUMNS ,the language changed by session (i have a radio button in  login page to chose the language ), it  is interactive  report .

Comment: work space =>jawad
user name  =>JAWADALNUAIMI54@GMAIL.COM
password  =>J@alnuaimi2020
application number (126113)  
I create this application for test only you can use this for help if you can

Comment: I deleted your XLIFF translation, it makes workflow more complicated, I think. Added new message in ar-jo language, it works. Please check and feel free to ask. There are free message-based translations for APEX, but unfortunately I haven't find it for your language: http://translate-apex.com/apex/f?p=800:TRANSLATIONS:::NO:::

Comment: it's working fine thanks for your support , i can do that in IG also

Comment: You are welcome! Please select my answer and vote if it useful.

Comment: thanks ans sub menu i can do that like (APEXIR_DATA_SORT) or no ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211608/discussion-between-ivan-dubashinskii-and-jaw).