# APEX LOV translation

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm using apex 20.2 and I have a multi-language application
is there any way to translate my LOV's based on app's language ?
I mean imagine we have a LOV and the display columns are {apple,orange,....}
I want to see lov's display columns based on app's language.

I've tried dynamic translation in shared component but it didn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your LOV dynamic or static?
If you use SQL statement for the LOV values, yes you can create dynamic translations as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/translating-data-that-supports-list-of-values.html#GUID-A694D367-069F-48DE-ADF7-E5F5EEBCD90F).
Afterwards, you need to re-construct your LOV as:

```
select ID as r, apex_lang.lang(NAME) as d
from COUNTRIES;
```

This way, the value displayed would be provided by the [APEX_LANG API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_lang.htm#AEAPI354).

Comment: thanks it did work! my LOV is dynamic .one more thing if I have Additional Display Columns in my lov , how do I translate column's headings ?

Comment: For column headings, you need to navigate to shared components -> globalization(text messages). There should be every text used in the application. If your headings do not appear, go to shared components -> translate -> seed translatable text.

Comment: I did it but it didn't work. let me give an example: 
select ID as r, apex_lang.lang(NAME) as d , city_name , capital_name
from COUNTRIES;

city_name and capital_name are my aditonal columns in my lov and I could name their headings whatever I want but I want headings to be translated dynamic like their records. Text messages didn’t help me through this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175272/oracle-apex-how-i-can-change-translate-action-menu-language-interactive-grid
Check this one

Comment: thank u ! how about static LOVs ? is there any way to translate them ?

Answer (score 0):

For column heading in LOV :
first in shared components--> Translate--->Seed and then publish
after that the only thing I should do is search my lov's column heading in **Translation Repository**
and then translate it and again seed and publish!